# functional equation, continuous functions.

Tags: functional-equations

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac {f(x+y)}{f(x-y)}=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)}$  $\forall$  $x\ne y$. Find all continuous functions $f$.

My progress:
Denote the assertion as $P(x,y)$. If $P(x,0)$ gives $f(0)=0$ and $P(x,-x)$ gives $f(x) = -f(-x)$. I don't know how to continue. Of course the additive cauchy functional equation works, I didn't found other solution so I think I have to prove that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: im 99% sure there's an cleaner solution, but i have been at this for hours now, im just happy to be done. If someone knows an better way PLEASE do let me know**

Here we go!

Claim 1: $f$ is an odd function

Proof: Already done by you. You reached $f(x) = -f(-x) \implies -f(x) = f(-x)$.$\blacksquare$

Claim 2: $f$ is injective.

Proof: Suppose there exists some $a,b$ such that $a\neq b$ and $f(a) = f(b)$. Then, it follows:

$\frac{f(a+b)}{f(a-b)} = \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{f(a)-f(b)}$

But since we assumed $f(a)=f(b)$, this is absurd, since it would mean the expression that holds for all real $x\neq y$ is undefined at some distinct real values.

But now we know $f$ is both continuous (by problem statement) and injective (by claim 2). Therefore, $f$ is either strictly increasing or stricly decreasing, as otherwise it can't be both continuous and injective.$\blacksquare$

Claim 3: If $f$ is increasing, it is unbounded.

Suppose not. Let $b$ be the least upper bound of $f$. Then, $f(x)<b$ for all $x$. We know $f$ is strictly increasing (and continuous) so, we can always find some $a$ such that $b-f(a) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Pick $\delta>0$. Then, $f(a+\delta)>f(a)$. Now, notice that:

$\frac{f(2a+\delta)}{f(\delta)} = \frac{f(a+\delta)+f(a)}{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}$

Notice that, as long as $\epsilon < f(a)$, we have that $f(a+\delta)+f(a) > 2f(a) > f(a) + \epsilon > b$.

$\frac{b}{f(\delta)} > \frac{f(2a+\delta)}{f(\delta)} = \frac{f(a+\delta)+f(a)}{f(a+\delta)-f(a)} > \frac{b}{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}$

Meaning,

$\frac{b}{f(\delta)} > \frac{b}{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}$

Notice $f(\delta)$ and $f(a+\delta)-f(a)$ are positive. So,

$f(\delta) < f(a+\delta) - f(a) \implies f(a+\delta) > f(a) + f(\delta)$

Suppose $f$ is increasing. Then, clearly, $\delta > 0$. And, in fact, any $\delta>0$ will satisfy the definition of $\delta$. So, choose $\delta>a$. This means $b>f(a+\delta) > f(a)+f(\delta) > f(a)+f(a) > b$ (absurd). So, if $f$ is increasing, it can't be bounded above. Further, since it is odd, it can't be bounded at all. $\blacksquare$

Claim 4: If $f$ is decreasing, it is unbounded.

Suppose some $f$ that is decreasing and bounded exists. Clearly, defining $g(x)=-f(x)$ gives us another solution to the original equation. But this solution must be increasing and bounded, from it's definition. But claim 3 says not such $g$ exists. Therefore, no such $f$ exists. $\blacksquare$

So, $f$ is strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing), continuous and unbounded.

Define $g_{x}(y)$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(g_{x}(y))$. Notice since our function $f$ is bijective, $g_{x}$ is well defined for any $x,y$.

Further, we can say:

$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)} = \frac{f(x+y)}{f(x-y)} =  \frac{f(x) + f(g_{x}(y))}{f(x)-f(g_{x}(y))}$

Meaning, $f(x)^{2} -f(x)f(g_{x}(y)) + f(x)f(y) -f(y)f(g_{x}(y)) = f(x)^{2} + f(x)f(g_{x}(y)) -f(x)f(y) - f(y)f(g_{x}(y)) \implies 2f(x)f(y) = 2f(x)f(g_{x}(y)) \implies f(y)=f(g_{x}(y))$

Since $f$ is injective, $y=g_{x}(y)$. Therefore, $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(g_{x}(y)) = f(x)+f(y)$. Meaning, any solution to our equation must satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. We finish by using the well known fact that the only continuous solutions of $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ are $f(x)=cx$ and $f(x)=0$. Substituting back into the original equation, we see only $f(x)=cx$ works.

Comment: The solutions are f(x)=ax.

Comment: oops, my bad, forgot the constant on cauchys F.E

Comment: should be good now? @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: You need to say $b$ is a least bound, not just any bound. Or $b = \sup f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: yep, you're right, my bad @aschepler